# OpenLayers - displaying the markers on the map

Tags: openlayers, markers

I can´t see the markers on the map. In the table i can see all the points but on the map it´s not displayed. 
I guess the problem is here:

```
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(venues.location.lat,venues.location.lng),icon));
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(venues.location.lat,venues.location.lng),icon.clone()));
```

when i put some coordinate instead `venues.location.lat,venues.location.lng` it display the marker.

...but have no idea how to solve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.7153,-117.1564&limit=14&radius=1000&client_id=PKAHBB1OAX0B000CG5UUYO4BXV0LWQWKFB51EK3XVNFJ2ULS&client_secret=RDPX01C01RHCYASZIKVH5XXMPVFIPLFHFP1D53UR4GUWQD50&v=20120101',
function(data) {
console.log(data); 
    $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
        content = '<p>Name: ' + venues.name + 
            ' Address: ' + venues.location.address + 
            ' Lat/long: ' + venues.location.lat + ', ' + venues.location.lng + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo("#venues");
        $('#table').append("<tr><td>" + venues.name + "</td><td>" + venues.location.address + "</td><td>" +venues.location.lat + "</td><td>" + venues.location.lng + "</td></tr >");

   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of the problems is that variable `venues` which is read via an AJAX request is not accessible from the OpenLayers block inside `<body>`. If you want to add each data point to the map you'll need to move the marker-adding code to the body of `$.each` callback.
Another problem is that, as its name implies, `OpenLayers.LonLat`'s constructor takes latitude as the first parameter, you're passing lat and lon in the wrong order, causing the markers to appear somewhere on Antarctica.

Here's a JSFiddle that fixes both these problems: http://jsfiddle.net/s9jGt/1/